# WooCommerce Option has disappeared

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Having a little bit of trouble with one of our Wordpress Multisites that uses WooCommerce. This issue has only just started occurring after the latest upgrade to Latest WP and latest version of WooCommerce

Woo Version = 6.4.0
Wordpress Version = 5.9.3

Note that this is not a permissions issue as we can actually add things like

edit.php?post_type=shop_order

to the end of the admin URL and gain access to order pages etc. So it's 100% not a user-level problem.

I have also done a bunch of suggestions which include turning off plugins to check conflicts. Still nothing. I have also deleted and reinstalled woo manually several times and still nothing.

Does anyone know if I could potentially write a piece of code that would force this to work? I know with functions.php we can hide specific menu items from the left-hand side but is there a way we could potentially force to show the woocommerce option?

Screen attached to explain where it is missing.

Thanks,
Glen

[image: Woocommerce Option has completely disappeared and so we cannot navigate to things such as orders and settings via the menu.]

Comment: [Fixed](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/pull/32623) in WooCommerce 6.4.1

Answer (score 0):

There is a change in the latest woocommerce version.

For the current fix, You can change menu core file 55 to '55.5' on line number: 64

woocommerce/includes/admin/class-wc-admin-menus.php

[image: '55.5' on line number: 64]